# How to register an extension with annotated variables in JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I have the following test class in which I’m registering the S3ProxyExtension:

```java
import org.gaul.s3proxy.junit.S3ProxyExtension;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.RegisterExtension;

@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@SpringBootTest(classes = { ABC.class })
public class ABCTest {
    @Value("${accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;
    @Value("${secretKey}")
    private String secretKey;
 
    @RegisterExtension
    S3ProxyExtension EXTENSION = S3ProxyExtension.builder().withPort(5444).withCredentials(accessKey, secretKey).build();
    // ...
}
```

How can I use the annotated variables accessKey  and secretKey, while registering the extension? Cause for now it throws an error “java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError”.

I have tried to use annotated variables while registering a Junit extension but it still throws a “java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError” error.

Comment: The problem is the usual lifecycle of the application and how the test generates its needed resources/configurations.
 Context and Application is created - Module will be registered and in the end when everything is ready the property are defined/created. So they are not available at the time when your extension is registered. TODO: Create the properties as a @Configuration which will be built before OR since it is a test use fallback/hardcoded default values since you should know them.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have created a class with : @Configuration public class TestConfig { }, but still the annotated values accessKey and secretKey are null before the extension is registered. Do you have please any working example? Thanks

Comment: If you make `S3ProxyExtension EXTENSION` static it would be created before JUnit runs its lifecycle and invokes the TestInstancePostProcessor (and Spring context).